# Different results between NodeJS and PL SQL executions (Oracle)

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql

PL statement:

```
 sca.pac_age_web_infm_supl.pro_gera_ssos_infm_supl(
i_cod_un_cons => :i_cod_un_cons (float),
i_num_cli => :i_num_cli (float),
i_nom_sist_orig => :i_nom_sist_orig (string),
i_cod_tipo_aces => :i_cod_tipo_aces (string),
i_cod_tipo_sol => :i_cod_tipo_sol (string),
i_cod_tipo_ger => :i_cod_tipo_ger (string),
i_ano_emis => :i_ano_emis (float),
i_qtd_mes_emis => :i_qtd_mes_emis (float),
i_cod_tipo_emis => :i_cod_tipo_emis (string),
i_cod_email => :i_cod_email (string),
i_cod_tipo_vin => :i_cod_tipo_vin (string),
i_cod_tipo_rel => :i_cod_tipo_rel (string),
i_sta_cobr_emis => :i_sta_cobr_emis (string),
i_vlr_cobr_emis => :i_vlr_cobr_emis (float),
o_cod_cpu_os => :o_cod_cpu_os,
o_num_seq_oper_os => :o_num_seq_oper_os,
o_num_seq_ger_os => :o_num_seq_ger_os,
o_cntd_arq => :o_cntd_arq,
o_cursor => :o_cursor,
o_msg_erro => :o_msg_erro);
end;
```

NodeJS function:

```
var sql = 'BEGIN PAC_AGE_WEB_INFM_SUPL.PRO_GERA_SSOS_INFM_SUPL(:i_cod_un_cons, :i_num_cli, :i_nom_sist_orig, :i_cod_tipo_aces, :i_cod_tipo_sol, :i_cod_tipo_ger, :i_ano_emis, :i_qtd_mes_emis, :i_cod_tipo_emis, :i_cod_email, :i_cod_tipo_vin, :i_cod_tipo_rel, :i_sta_cobr_emis, :i_vlr_cobr_emis, :o_cod_cpu_os, :o_num_seq_oper_os, :o_num_seq_ger_os, :o_cntd_arq, :o_cursor, :o_msg_erro); END;';
```

Any tips on why my func returning ORA-01036?
All my bindvards correctly typed.

Comment: You need to give all the calliing code.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing colon, here:

```
:i_sta_cobr_emis, i_vlr_cobr_emis, :o_cod_cpu_os
                 ^
                 |
```

Comment: Thank you! I have some line breaks and ended up removing the column in the question. I edited the question to include it

Answer (score 0):

Solved by droping the object and recompiling it. Thanks, guys!